# How to compare screenshot with saved png image with Sikuli

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I am using the following to try and compare a screenshot with a saved .png image but it is not working.  The screenshot and .png file are the same but I am getting the following error in eclipse:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
    expected [P(C:/Users/pauljos/tmpDirectory.png) S: 0.7] but found [org.sikuli.script.ScreenImage@58fdd99]
```

I am using Sikuli in eclipse and here is my script:

```
Screen screen = new Screen(); 
Pattern pattern4 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\pauljos\\tmpDirectory.png");
screen.click("C:\\Users\\pauljos\\explorerIcon.PNG");
screen.click("C:\\Users\\pauljos\\explorerWhiteSpace.PNG");
screen.type("c:/tmp");
screen.type(Key.ENTER);
ScreenImage img = screen.capture();
sikuli_assert.assertEquals(img, pattern4);
```

Comment: What is `sikuli_assert`? Is that a helper class that you have created? If so, include its code in your question otherwise how do we know how the `assertEquals` is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to assert incompatible data types Pattern & ScreenImage. you should something like below.

Screen screen = new Screen(); 
BufferedImage img1=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\Users\pauljos\tmpDirectory.png"));

BufferedImage img = screen.capture().getImage();

if(img1.equals(img)){

//both images are equal
}